# Windows 10 laptop won't connect to WiFi at home, but can elsewhere. Other devices can connect to WiFi at home

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, connection, internet-connection

My Windows 10 laptop can connect to my home WiFi, but the connection is extremely slow when it works at all. When waiting for a website to load, I see 'Resolving host...' etc. in the lower left-hand corner and even when a site has loaded, the 'wheel' is still spinning as if it's still loading.

Other devices, phones, tablets, etc. can all connect to the WiFi without issues, which would suggest a laptop problem.

However...

The laptop can connect to any other WiFi network without any issues whatsoever, including my phone data connection when I tether to it, so clearly the laptop is OK too.

Recently having had Sky internet installed, I thought perhaps it was that. A new hub has been sent out and installed, but to no avail - Other devices can still connect, but the laptop cannot.

There doesn't seem to be any method to this madness and so pinpointing the root cause is difficult.

I've tried rebooting laptop, rebooting modem, updating network adapter drivers, etc. - All the usual areas of concern, but I'm still not getting a reliable, quick connection.

Sky broadband is showing 80mbps coming into the house, so there should be no speed issues even with a few devices connected. Other devices are fast when connected to the network, so the service itself is fine.

Please help if you have any idea where to go with this next...!

Comment: Any specific DNS settings in the details of that connection? Did you try to remove the connection and add it again?

Comment: try this one, open cmd, and write this commands: 
IPCONFIG /renew
IPCONFIG /flushdns
IPCONFIG /registerdns